# Type of solution (as the critical point of the energy functional) after doing scaling to the PDE.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations

Now I have a nonlinear elliptic PDE, if I do scaling such as $u=\lambda v$ and then get a new PDE, then I turn to study the new equation since it has a simpler form. My question is easy to understand: **if I prove that for the new PDE, all the solutions are not the local minimum of the energy functional (of the new PDE), can we say that all the solution of the PDE before scaling are also not the local minimum of the energy functional (of the old PDE)?**

I have checked their second derivations, they are not the same since we have the scaling. But they are basically the same question, I think it's natural to ask whether the type of critical points will be the same as well?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, I don’t see why this would be true. Forget about PDEs, if I have a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with a local max at $x=2$ and a local min at $x=1$ then $x=2$ is a critical point that isn’t a local min , but $2\lambda$ with $\lambda =1/2$ is a local min

Comment: For the PDE case, I don’t see why you couldn’t have two solutions $u,v$ in the same span, but one is a local max and one is a local min of the same functional

Comment: Thanks for your example @JackT, but my question is a little bit different, I mean that after scaling, all the solutions are not the local minimum, so for the function case, before scaling all the solutions (thus the point where the derivative is 0) are also not the local minimum I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Gonçalo, I just read some papers on stable solution, which is the solution that is the local minimum of the energy functional. A famous result is that for $\Delta u + e^u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $2 \le n \le 9$, there is no stable solution (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X0700218X). So I wonder if I study $\lambda \Delta v + e^{\lambda v} = 0 $ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $2 \le n \le 9$, can I also draw the conclusion that there is no stable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after seeing some of the comments, I think the answer to your question is yes.

Let $$ I[v] = \int_\Omega L(\nabla u, u,x)\, dx $$ be some functional which we’d like to minimise over a set of admissible functions $\mathcal A$. My interpretation of your question is: if there are no stable local minimums of $I$ if and only if there are no stable local minimums of $I_\lambda$ with $I_\lambda [v]:=I[\lambda v]$ and $\lambda >0$. (Correct me if this is wrong)

For simplicity, assume that $\mathcal A$ is a vector space (often this is the case). Then $u$ is a local minimum of $I_\lambda$ if $$ \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg \vert_{\varepsilon=0} I_\lambda [u+\varepsilon \eta]=0 \text{ and } \frac{d^2}{d\varepsilon^2}\bigg \vert_{\varepsilon=0} I_\lambda [u+\varepsilon \eta]\geq 0 $$ for all $\eta \in \mathcal A$. But clearly, $$\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg \vert_{\varepsilon=0} I_\lambda [u+\varepsilon \eta]= \lambda\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg \vert_{\varepsilon=0}  I[\lambda u+\varepsilon \eta] \text{ and } \frac{d^2}{d\varepsilon^2}\bigg \vert_{\varepsilon=0} I_\lambda [u+\varepsilon \eta]=\lambda^2 \frac{d^2}{d\varepsilon^2}\bigg \vert_{\varepsilon=0} I [\lambda u+\varepsilon \eta] ,$$ so $u$ is a local minimum of $I_\lambda$ if and only if $\lambda u$ is a local minimum of $I$.

Comment: @whpowell96 that’s an interesting remark. I don’t agree with your final sentence though - my definition is for all $\eta$, so it’s more like saying at the critical point $f_{vv}$\geq 0$ for all $v\in \mathbb S^{n-1}$. For a $C^2$ function, I think this is enough to conclude there is a local min at the critical point

Comment: @whpowell96 Also, the definition I used above is just the standard definition of stable solution in the calculus of variations